# how to loop class name by *ngFor using angular10

Tags: angular10

**columnClass: string[]** = ['name', 'email', 'phn', 'city', 'state', '', 'w-40'];

`<td *ngFor="let col of columnClass" class="pr-20 {{col}}">`

`string[]` is in one **component.ts** and `html` is in another **component.html**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [bind to the class](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding#class-binding) to use variables inside of it.

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columnClass" class="pr-20" [class]="col">
```